# PDOException: SQLSTATE[HYT00]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired on Centos 7

Tags: php, sql-server, centos7, sqlsrv, php-7.3

[image: PDOException-SQLSTATEHYT00]

I am facing the problem with PDOException even I installed pdo_sqlsrv PHP extension for php 7.3 on Centos 7. I think the problem is due to different driver version I am using and the one on the Microsoft SQL database server. Can someone tell how to solve the problem?

Comment: Unless I recall incorrectly, I'm don't think that ODBC Driver 17 works with the **unsupported** SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I can call the same ip, the same port with same authentication via SQL Server Management Studio from my compouter that is windows 10. There is no problem to access.

Comment: SSMS doesn't use ODBC.

Comment: I don't know exactly about it but I use also Microsoft Access that needs odbc to connect Microsoft SQL Database server from the same laptop where SQL Server Management Studio I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened by firewall that was blocking the server and there were nothing problem in odbc and other php modules installation to connect Microsoft SQL server. Anyway, thanks @Luma.